# Android Studio's emulator with black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have a problem when I tried to start my AVD in android studio. It was working fine but all of a sudden it just turns black. I have tried to restart my pc but it didnt help. Any solution? Or is there any AVD application that I can use because android studio's AVD is kinda slow.

Comment: Recommend Android Device testing (best speed, not multi screen), Genymotion (speed and multi screen)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download/) instead. It is faster than android studio's AVD and easy to use. Also in some cases, you might have riot vanguard (riot games anti cheat system), and you need to uninstall it to use android studio's AVD.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens to me from time to time. To fix this, open your AVD Manager. Then, click the arrow to the far right. Finally, click Cold Boot Now.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I know how to solve it

Answer (score -1):

I will say it will be better if you use physical mobile devices and the step to use that is mentioned below:

Pre-requesting:

- Android Studio
- USB cable
- Android Device

Steps:

- Enable USB
  debugging([Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options))
- Automatically get device driver install on the system.
- Run your app using a connected device. check ou this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app)

Why I am suggesting to you because this will improve your productivity of coding.

If you want multiple device testing then only go through Virtual emulator such as BlueStack, GenyMotion, AndY which I used and prefer more due to of less memory uses.